# ZipEntry to Stream with monodroid

Tags: mono, zip, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to unzip a file in Android using Monodroid. I can get my ZipEntry with the Property NextEntry, but now I really need to convert this ZipEntry to a simple Stream.

EDIT:

Some part of my code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Java.Util.Zip;
using File = System.IO.File;

  public void ExtractFile(Stream ZipFile, Action<String, Stream> WriteFile)
        {
            ZipInputStream zis;
            try
            {
                zis = new ZipInputStream(ZipFile);
                ZipEntry entry;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;

                while ((entry = zis.NextEntry) != null)
                {
                  // HERE I need to call my WriteFile action with a stream
                }
 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic.Zip, then you can get it easily:
zipentry.InputStream

Comment: Hi, I'm not using Ionic.Zip so I don't have the InputStream property